# java.io.IOException: Stream closed when trying to initialize RestAssured using java(11.0.9) with "No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.Object;.each()"

Tags: java, groovy, automated-tests, rest-assured

I am getting following exception while executing using jar. Getting following error when trying to initialize RestAssured Object:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:165)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:342)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:594)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:569)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$DgmMethodRecord.loadDgmInfo(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:195)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:199)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:86)
        at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:37)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.isValidWeakMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:284)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassForClass(ClassInfo.java:254)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:310)
        at io.restassured.authentication.NoAuthScheme.$getStaticMetaClass(NoAuthScheme.groovy)
        at io.restassured.authentication.NoAuthScheme.<init>(NoAuthScheme.groovy)
        at io.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:354)
```

Followed by :

```
 => groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.Object;.each() is applicable for argument types: (io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$_header_closure8) values: [io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$_header_closure8@3ecedf21]
Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), equals(java.lang.Object), wait(long, int), getAt(java.lang.Integer)
       org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:70)
       org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
       org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
       org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
       org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
       [...]
       Suppressed: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.Object;.each() is applicable for argument types: (io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$_header_closure8) values: [io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$_header_closure8@2f19f2aa]
Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), equals(java.lang.Object), wait(long, int), getAt(java.lang.Integer)
         org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:70)
         org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
         org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
         org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callSafe(AbstractCallSite.java:96)
         io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.header(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:848)
```

I have tried adding couple of dependencies as follows:

1. restAssured : "io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.4.0"
2. groovyAll: "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.3"
3. groovy   : "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.3"
4. groovyXML: "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:3.0.3"
5. httpclient: "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13"
6. httpmime: "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.13"
7. junit:"junit:junit:4.13.2"

Also, tried adding :

1. implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0
2. testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
3. testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
4. testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.16.1'

I have also experimented with multiple combinations of version (latest ones as well) or just using rest-assured dependency. Till now, nothing seem to work.

Here is the code line on which it fails: RestAssured.baseURI = System.getProperty("");

Need help to resolve this exception.

Comment: Could you add the code that can reproduce the problem? and which java version you are using?

Comment: I am using java 11. Code runs properly in local execution, but fails during deployment. Here is the code line on which it fails: RestAssured.baseURI = System.getProperty("<some property>");

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 I have added more details in my query.

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and examine output for possible dependency conflicts. You should fix your pom so that conflicting dependencies which transitevly come from rest-assured should not also come from higher dependency hierarchy nodes.